# Is there a non-interactive way to regenerate OSS chef 11 validator key?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm working on a method of periodically re-generating the chef-validator key from an OSS chef installation so I can upload it to an AWS bucket I'm setting up for CloudFormation bootstrapping of new Chef clients.

I'd like to write some small (ideally) bash script which I can run via cron or on demand, or if a key compromise is suspected, to do the following:
1. Re-generate the chef-validator key
2. Upload the new validator to an S3 bucket for use by new clients when I bootstrap them via a custom CloudFormation UserData script

I can trigger the creation of a new validator from this URL, I think, interactively:

https://chef.example.com/clients/chef-validator/edit

where I can check the box to regenerate the private key.

Is there a way to do this via an API call which can be wrapped in a bash script, so it can run non-interactively in a cron-driven script? Would love to see code if anyone's done this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `knife client reregister chef-validator -f validator.pem`. It will regenerate the private and public key of the chef client *chef-validator* and store the private key to file *validator.pem*.

See [knife client reference](http://docs.opscode.com/knife_client.html#reregister) for details.